# argument type object is not assignable to parameter type 'Sitecore.Data.Items.Item'

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

I want to bind sitecore data (child Items) to repeater. In the Markup Code I am getting the error mentioned in title of this question.

I am getting error basically on this line:

```
<sc:Text runat="server" ID="Title" Item="<%# Container.DataItem %>"/>
```

Here is the Mark up code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterExample" runat="server">
             <ItemTemplate>
                <h3>
                    <sc:Text runat="server" ID="Title" Item="<%# Container.DataItem %>"/>
                </h3> 
             </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RepeaterExample.DataSource = Sitecore.Context.Item.GetChildren();
    RepeaterExample.DataBind();
}
```

I am new to sitecore, I am taking help from [sitecore Wiki](http://sitecorewiki.net/Data_Binding)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to cast the Container.DataItem to Sitecore.Data.Items.Item.

```
<sc:Text runat="server" ID="Title" Item="<%# Container.DataItem as Sitecore.Data.Items.Item %>"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But Now I am getting the exception: Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Stack empty.

Comment: You also need to specify the Field attribute.
ex: <sc:Text runat="server" ID="Title" Field="Name" Item="<%# Container.DataItem as Sitecore.Data.Items.Item %>"/>